# Why is the result of uint32_t becoming octal number automatically?

Tags: c++, uint32-t

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t n1 = 00000000000000000000000000001000;
    uint32_t n2 = 00000000000000000000000000000100;
    cout << n2; 
}
```

When I use Visual Studio 2013 (C++), I am getting the result as 64.

Why is this turning to octal number system instead of binary?

Comment: Where did you ask the computer to interpret it as binary? Not realising that it would be an octal literal I can understand, but then why would you not expect decimal instead?

Answer (score 3):

That's because a number with a leading `0` is considered to be an octal number:

```
auto num = 04; //Octal number
```

In C++14 and later, if you want to specify binary numbers, you will have to use the `0b` prefix:

```
uint32_t n2 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000100;
              ^^
```

If you can't use C++14, you will have to use bit shifts or similar techniques to get the desired result.

For decimal numbers, you will *have* to get rid of the leading `0`s.

Comment: Note that binary notation requires C++14 or later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, added :) Thanks

Comment: Not all numbers, just integer literals.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a numeric literal with `0` means you want it interpreted as octal, which is what I assume you meant when you used "octonary", a word I haven't seen before and, while it appears to be a real word, you'll probably get some blank stares if you use it :-)

This treatment as octal is as per the standard, `C++11 2.14.2 Integer literals /1`:

> An octal integer literal (base eight) begins with the digit 0 and consists of a sequence of octal digits.

For binary numbers, probably the easiest way to do it is with bit shifting (pre C++14):

```
uint32_t n1 = 1u << 3;
uint32_t n2 = 1u << 2;
```

C++14 provides the `0b` prefix, akin to the `0x` one for hexadecimal numbers but I'm not entirely convinced that's as readable as the other option if you still use a large number of leading zeros:

```
uint32_t n1 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001000;
uint32_t n2 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000100;
```

Seasoned coders, of course, can instantly map from binary to hex so would probably just use:

```
uint32_t n1 = 0x00000008;
uint32_t n2 = 0x00000004;
```